# Adding several times together Carbon Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7, php-carbon

Pulling a set of results each has a period of time (amount of time spend on a job)
I need to be able to add together each amount of time to give me a total.
My basic script below.

(Controller)

```
     $Yesterday = DB::table('InOutUserCurrentStatus')
     ->where('Email','=',$UID)
    ->where('Date', '=', $Yest )->get();
```

(View)

```
      TotalA = new(DateTime)
      @foreach($Yesterday as $Yest)
         $newtime = Carbon::parse($Yest->TimeStamp)
         ??????
      @endforeach
```

Idea would be $Total =+ $newtime, but I found this just throws up errors.

> Object of class Carbon\Carbon could not be converted to int

Comment: Why not just use `SUM()` in the query?  `Object of class Carbon\Carbon could not be converted to int`  So if `results each has a period of time (amount of time spend on a job)` are a number of seconds, which happen to be an int, you can just add them.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why do you run such calculation in your view?

Comment: I may be easier if I use strtotime and sum the results?